# How to set lifetime for doctrine result and query cache globally?

Tags: doctrine, zend-framework2, query-builder

Is it possible to set lifetime for doctrine result and query cache globally (not second level cache). I do not want do it for every query, like below:

```
$queryBuilder
            ->getQuery()
            ->useResultCache(true)
            ->setQueryCacheLifetime(7 * 24 * 60 * 60)
            ->setResultCacheLifetime(7 * 24 * 60 * 60)
            ->getSingleScalarResult()
```

Comment: Which kind of cache are you using? Which version of Symfony are you using? This question looks similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64389503/how-to-set-a-default-cache-lifetime-for-doctrine-in-symfony-4-4